# Copy on Write - COW - what happened after the page is modified

Tags: copy-on-write

I'm learning the copy-on-write technique. I can understand that parent and child process share the same address space. When the parent or child want to modify the page, so that page will be copied to private memory of process then modified it.

So my question is, assume that child process is modified the page, then complete and terminate. How the modified data? is it still there and visible to parent process and other child processes?

In short, if child process modified the page, and what happen next to parent and other child processes for that modified page/data?

I read the COW concepts and understand it basic principles but not sure how deep I understand.

Answer (score 0):

**In short** - the parent does not have access to the child process data. Neither do any other siblings. The moment the child process terminates, all its modifications is lost.

Remember, COW is just an optimization. From the processes point of view, they don't even realize it is copy on write. From their perspective, each process has its own copy of the memory space.

**Long answer, what happens behind the scenes:**

*Note, I am simplifying some corner case, not everything is 100% accurate but this is the idea.

Each process has its own page table, which maps process virtual addresses to physical pages.

At some point, the parent process calls fork. At this step, a child process is created, its VMA descriptors are duplicated (there are certain rules on how that is done, with intermediate chain etc, not going to deep dive into this). What is important is that at this stage, child and parent virtual addresses are pointing to the same physical addresses.

Next, all pages are made read only.

At this point, if either child or parent try to write to a certain page, it will cause a page fault. They can read freely, however.

Now assume child writes to a page. This causes a page fault. This page fault is caught by the kernel. So the kernel understands it is COW now. What it does is creating a separate copy of a physical page for child.

So at this point, child and parent have same virtual address pointing to two different physical addresses.

That should answer your question. Parent cannot access other process physical pages. The virtual address is the same, but that does not matter. When child dies, its pages are recycled, and all changes are lost.

Comment: Hi Yuri, thank for your answer, I understand the principle. So with your explanation, when the child process terminate, all modification were lost. For my thinking, the modification should somehow write to disk and parent process and other siblings should refresh to see the modified data right? For example, if user A is reading page 1, user B is modifying page 1 as well, then user B done with modification and save and close his program/process. So user A is still not seeing the updates? This makes me confused here.

Comment: Please clarify, what memory are you talking about? Are you talked about shared memory mapped files? There is no copy on write in this case at all. Private memory mapped files? In this case changes are not propagated to the disk at all.

Comment: Hi Yuri, for here you stated "Now assume child writes to a page. This causes a page fault. This page fault is caught by the kernel. So the kernel understands it is COW now. What it does is creating a separate copy of a physical page for child."  I mean that modified separate copy of a physical page for child will be discarded after child terminated? it will not be merged with the parent and other childs? so all the changes will here will not be written to disk? so that the modified copy is useless here? and what is the benefit of the modified copy here?

Comment: I mean if we modified a word documents then save it, and other people later can see the changes. For example, if we have shared a word document with sharepoint, many people can view and edit concurrently and all changes will be saved. so this appoach does not apply in COW?

Comment: @Phat I think you misunderstood what COW is needed for. What you describe is a shared memory model, when multiple processes can modify the same memory area, and see the changes. It has nothing to do with COW. In case of a shared memory, multiple processes map same physical pages each one to its own memory space. When one process modifies the memory, others see the modifications. If the memory is file backed, it is more complex, but eventually the final version of the memory is propagated to the disk.

Comment: COW is an optimization mechanism, that works in an opposite direction - when 2 processes have SEPARATE memory spaces, and cannot see each others. The optimization is, that after fork, the two processes may contain memory regions with identical data (this happens after fork). So, instead of actually holding two copies of this memory, kernel is holding one, as long as there are only reads. After first write, the data is no longer identical. So only then two actual copies of the memory region are created.

Comment: I understood the situation right now. Thank you Yuri for your excellent explanation & information here.